# How to remove customviews added programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In one of the iPad Application, I am working I have added custom views to a view. This works fine but now I want to remove all the custom views added. How do I do that?

Following is my code for adding custom views

```
for (int col=0; col<colsInRow; col++) {
    //  NSLog(@"Column Number is%d",col);
    x=gapMargin+col*width+gapH*col;


    //self.styleButton=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    ComponentCustomView *componentCustomobject=[[ComponentCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    componentCustomobject.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    componentCustomobject.componentLabel.text=[appDelegate.componentsArray objectAtIndex:row];
    [self.formConatinerView addSubview:componentCustomobject];
    tempCount1++;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove all the subviews of type ComponentCustomView from your parent views

```
for (UIView *view in self.formConatinerView.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[ComponentCustomView class]) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray  *arr = [self.view subViews];

for (UIView *view in arr) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[ComponentCustomView class]) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if removing objects from the array being iterated (in this case `subviews`) was safe or not (I remember reading something about a discrepancy between Mac OS X and iOS, but not sure...); Unless property `subviews` returns a copy of the internal array (very likely since the internal array needs to be mutable), a 100% safe, just-in-case way to do it would be this:

```
NSArray* copyOfSubviews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[myView subviews]];
// Explicitly made mutable in an attempt to prevent Cocoa from returning 
//  the same array, instead of making a copy. Another, tedious option would 
//  be to create an empty mutable array and add the elements in subviews one by one.

for(UIView* view in copyOfSubviews){
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[ComponentCustomView class]){
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

// (This is for non-ARC only:)
[copyOfSubviews release];
```